# I've 2 columns. Ex in Column A Tom; Hema and in column B Tom. So in column C I need a formula that if Hema isnt there in B, it should show hema's name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've 2 columns. Ex in Column A Tom; Hema (In the same cell) and in column B Tom. So in column C I need a formula that if Hema isnt there in B, it should show hema's name in column C. In column A there can be multiple names and semicolon as a differentiator. Need to match column A to B and if the name which is there in A isn't there in B then give the name in C. The names can be multiple

I need a formula or any other possible way

Comment: please post your input as well as your desired output

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Once you start combining information in one cell, which must be split, I have the tendency of going for an UDF (User-Defined Function) instead of a complicated formula.

Comment: Hi @Dominique Sir, so do you think a `UDF` user defined function is not a complicated one, using `VBA--UDF` you think is the easiest way as against an excel formula can you explain this. So saying only UDF some may or may not be aware you should give them full information on how to write a UDF, like how to create it. Because people usually opt for formulas when VBA is not needed and can be achievable. Also `VBA` wont work in Excel for web, hope you know this

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Looks like you are a true disliker of UDFs :-) I mean that an UDF gives the possibility to add comment, use meaningful variable names, ..., all the things which increase readability over a sometimes complex formula without the mentioned features. I was not aware of Excel for web, what is that by the way?

Comment: Sir, pardon me and with due respect to your comments, i am not saying about like or dislike, the reason to develop such newer functions in excel by the team only to make life easier so it can work for any environment, like excel for desktop app or web. So does `LET()` function helps in creating variables. The development of these function have some reasons behind it. Here you can know about [What is Excel For Web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/work-in-excel-for-the-web-812f519f-8db1-4de2-81d2-d7f3510168ca)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of achieving the desired output:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=MAP(A1:A2,B1:B2,LAMBDA(x,y,
 LET(z, TEXTSPLIT(x,"; "), 
 TEXTJOIN("; ",1,FILTER(z,ISERR(SEARCH(z,"; "&y&"; ")),"")))))
```

---

- Using `MAP()` function to **map each value** in the array, and pass a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations to get the desired output.
- Using `LET()` function to create a variable using `TEXTSPLIT()` function which will be used twice making it easy to read the steps as well as reduces the working capacity by avoiding the repetition of redundant codes.
- So, the `TEXTSPLIT()` function splits the Column `A` values column wise using a delimiter, which is further used within `SEARCH()` function as the **[find_text]** argument within the Column `B` values.
- The above shall return some numbers that is the starting position and some error values as well. Those errors are transformed to `TRUE` using `ISERR()` function, this is because those `TRUE`s are required outputs which we need.
- Wrapping within `FILTER()` to return the `TRUE` values and lastly using `TEXTJOIN()` function to return as single cell value delimited by semi-colon.

---

Well without using `LAMBDA()` helper function:

[image]

---

```
=LET(z,TEXTSPLIT(A1,"; "),TEXTJOIN("; ",1,FILTER(z,ISERR(SEARCH(z,B1)),"")))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions: there's a maximum of 2 names in column A, a semicolon is always the delimiter.

```
=IFERROR( IF(TEXTBEFORE(XLOOKUP(B1,A1,A1,"",1),";",,,,"")= B1 , TEXTAFTER(A1,";",,,,"") , TEXTAFTER(A1,";",,,,"") , IF(TRIM(TEXTAFTER(XLOOKUP(B1,A1,A1,"",1),";",,,,""))=B1;TEXTAFTER(A1,";",,,,""),"No Match"))
```

Hope it helps. I guess someone can come up with a shorter version.

Comment: @Dominique typo/translation error indeed, thanks for noting!